# moving files C# always throws an exception

Tags: c#, file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuGRa.png)

```
public void MoveFiles(string[]filesDics, string to, FilesErrorDelegate filesError) {
            FileInfo f;
            foreach (string file in filesDics) {
                try {
                    f = new FileInfo(file);
                    f.MoveTo(to + "\\" + f.Name);
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                    bool ifContinue = filesError(file);
                    if (ifContinue) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }







and here i am using the function:
private void BtnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string[] filesNamesArray = GetFilesArray();
            mf.MoveFiles(filesNamesArray, @"C:\Users\76599\Documents\filesManager", delegates[selectedError]);

        }
```

does anyone know??
it is very weird becuz that my friend used exactly the same code in their computer and it did work!

the exception says there is another process using this file. but i don't see any other process is using it.

thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What exactly is the exception? Maybe it's to do with file permissions or incorrect paths. We can't know without you telling us the details

Comment: the exception says there is another process using this file.

Comment: well it is a problem of c# becuz if i try to move it via Windows it works. the problem is in c#. any more answers??? it is really weird

Comment: The problem is not C#, its likely your code,. Specifically I'm guessing you have the file open somewhere. However, it could be as benign as a virus checker. Though 98 times out of 100 its your code

Answer (score 1):

If another process is locking the file, you won't be able to move the file up until the other process is closed.

You can find which process is locking the file using approach such as:
https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows-10/

You also need to not have an command prompt, notepad++ or windows explorer open within those directory as they would lock the file. But a lot of other process has the same behavior.

Alternatively, for files which are locked, instead of moving them, you could copy them and leave the original lock file depending on your needs.
You could also have a list of files which were locked and attempt to delete them at a future time. It is also possible that locked file can't be copied depending on the type of lock, which the only solution would be to close the process locking the file.

Comment: there is no process using this file.and no windows explorer... and coping doesnt help too

Comment: @user14502245 can you give us information about the file in question? there are some files which aren't handled well in the system as they are reserved such as CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9 and I believe they also can't be used within the extension.
If you gave more information about the file in question which is causing the issue, we might be able to see something. Unless your own application is the one locking the file before moving it, but you claim your friend can use it, so i'm clueless